# Callback to a non-static C++ Member Function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, callback

I would like someone to shed some light this code snippet, which confuses me.

```
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   // 3.5 Example B: Callback to member function using a global variable
   // Task: The function 'DoItB' does something that implies a callback to
   //       the member function 'Display'. Therefore the wrapper-function
   //       'Wrapper_To_Call_Display is used.

   #include <iostream.h>   // due to:   cout

   void* pt2Object;        // global variable which points to an arbitrary object

   class TClassB
   {
   public:

      void Display(const char* text) { cout << text << endl; };
      static void Wrapper_To_Call_Display(char* text);

      /* more of TClassB */
   };


   // static wrapper-function to be able to callback the member function Display()
   void TClassB::Wrapper_To_Call_Display(char* string)
   {
       // explicitly cast global variable <pt2Object> to a pointer to TClassB
       // warning: <pt2Object> MUST point to an appropriate object!
       TClassB* mySelf = (TClassB*) pt2Object;

       // call member
       mySelf->Display(string);
   }


   // function does something that implies a callback
   // note: of course this function can also be a member function
   void DoItB(void (*pt2Function)(char* text))
   {
      /* do something */

      pt2Function("hi, i'm calling back using a global ;-)");   // make callback
   }


   // execute example code
   void Callback_Using_Global()
   {
      // 1. instantiate object of TClassB
      TClassB objB;


      // 2. assign global variable which is used in the static wrapper function
      // important: never forget to do this!!
      pt2Object = (void*) &objB;


      // 3. call 'DoItB' for <objB>
      DoItB(TClassB::Wrapper_To_Call_Display);
   }
```

**Question 1:** Regarding this function call:

```
DoItB(TClassB::Wrapper_To_Call_Display)
```

Why does `Wrapper_To_Call_Display` not take any arguments, although it is supposed to take a `char*` argument according to its declaration?

**Question  2:** `DoItB` is declared as

```
void DoItB(void (*pt2Function)(char* text))
```

What I’ve understood so far is that `DoItB` takes a function pointer as argument, but why does the function call `DoItB(TClassB::Wrapper_To_Call_Display)` take `TClassB::Wrapper_To_Call_Display` as argument even tough it’s not a pointer?

Thanx in advance

Source of code snippet: http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C/C++ when a function name is used with no parameters - that is no parenthesis - it is a pointer to a function.  So `TClassB::Wrapper_To_Call_Display` is a pointer to the address in memory where the code for the function is implemented.

Since `TClassB::Wrapper_To_Call_Display` is a pointer to a `void` function that takes a single `char*` it's time is `void (*)(char* test)` so it matches the type required by `DoItB`.